# Spread syntax of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I completely understand the spread syntax of javascript. We use it before an object to rerieve all its properties at once. But recently I saw the spread operator being used for a function, and that function was `createForms` of `react-redux-forms`. It was supplied to `combineReducer` like this

```
combineReducer({
   ...createForms({something here})
})
```

I was just wondering what spread operator does before a function.

Please help me to understand this.

Thank You!

Comment: *We use it before an object to rerieve all its properties at once*. Same thing happens there. `createForms` function will return an object.

Comment: `createForms({something here})` is an object. `createForms` is the function. Spread applies to the object, not the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It spreads the return value of the function.

```js
function returnAnObject() {
  return {
    example: "awesome!",
    hello: "world"
  }
}

console.log({
  console: true,
  ...returnAnObject()
})
```